# Even and odd Dyck paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Call a Dyck path even when its height is even and call it odd if its height is odd.
Let $E_n$ be the number of even Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n-2,0)$ and $O_n$ the odd ones.

> Question 1: For which $n$ is the sequence $a_n=E_n-O_n$ positive? Is it infinitely often negative and infinitely often positive? Can $a_n$ be zero for $n>3$?

> Question 2: Is there a good upper bound for $|a_n|$?

Comment: Formula for the number of Dyck paths of given length and height: https://mathoverflow.net/q/319582